# How to make countdown time not back to default time if page refresh

Tags: jquery, countdown

So, i have small quiz with timer mode. I set 2 minutes to answer my question but after 1 minutes user refresh the page, timer back to 2 minutes

I follow countdown library http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
var def = 2 * 60 * 1000;
var now = new Date();
var timer = new Date(now.getTime() + def);
$('#countdown').countdown({until: timer});
```

I need to record 1 minutes left, maybe using cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie is best way ? but how ? somebody can give me example code ?

Comment: Cookie or LocalStorage javascript storing a counter value should do fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think a cookie would work best for this. When a user starts the quiz, set a cookie with the value set to current server date/time.

Check for a cookie each time the page loads, and if it exists, compare the cookie value to the current time to get the time left on the quiz.

from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp:

> With JavaScript: a cookie can be created like this:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

> You can also add an expiry date (in UTC or GMT time). By default, the
>   cookie is deleted when the browser is closed:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00
GMT";
```

> With a path parameter, you can tell the browser what path the cookie
>   belongs to. By default, the cookie belongs to the current page.

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00
GMT; path=/";
```

or with a simple jquery plugin: 
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: thanks you for your response, i use jquery cookie to handle this problem